# How to implement Spring Security on my Spring 4.0 RestFul web service?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, restful-authentication

I just developed a simple restful web service by using Spring 4.0 and Hibernate 4.0, so it is without `beans.xml` file.

I would like to implement a Spring Security on the web service, since the roles will be performed on the HTTP functions `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE`, i.e. only admin who is allowed to `DELETE`, manager is allowed to do both `POST` and `GET` and the user can only `GET` data.

I'm looking for a detailed tutorial with example to implement Spring Security? or Do you think there is an easier security mechanism regardless it's strength?

Comment: Here is a similar [question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242604/authentication-and-authorization-in-rest-services-with-liferay/28333815#28333815)

Comment: Thank you, looked helpful but there is still some unclear points in that description. If I find a tutorial with complete example, will be better.

Comment: You can take a look at [this sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-rest).

Comment: Thanks, however the project you mentioned is xml configuration-based and Im looking for annotation-based spring security without xml file.

Comment: Here the code will help you definatly : https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-rest-security

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just found that they in [Spring.io](http://Spring.io) added a detailed tutorial with real example developed by Java 8 in [their own website](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/), so it is completely annotation-based, which helps for building a RESTful webservice with Spring, testing it and also **securing** it.

It is really awesome, located [HERE](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)