# Spring Boot + Spring Security Restful Login

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

How would I go about securing a spring boot web service with spring security using java configurations and not xml? I need this to be a pseudo-RESTful service that returns a 401 response code on failed authentication and does not involve a custom login page. On a successful authentication, JSESSIONID should be returned and subsequently sent with every request.

Can someone provide a coded example of how to do this as I am completely lost? The Spring guides (for whatever reason) do not cover anything like this for spring boot secured with spring security.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242604/authentication-and-authorization-in-rest-services-with-liferay

Answer (score 3):

Have you read through Dave Syer's blog posts on securing spring boot web apps? He's got a great 5-part post on this subject:

SSO with OAuth2: Angular JS and Spring Security Part V
http://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v